# Json.NET deserializing Mongo ObjectId is giving the wrong result

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, json.net

I'm using the official Mongo C# Driver, and RestSharp to call a Rest Api with Json.NET to perform my serialization/deserialization. Say I have a Person class as follows, which I'd like to POST & GET:

```
public class Person
{
  [JsonProperty("_id"),JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
  public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I create a new Person object:

```
var person = new Person{Id = ObjectId.GenerateId(),Name='Joe Bloggs'};
```

POST it, and on the server I see the following which is correct:

```
{ _id: 52498b56904ee108c99fbe88, name: 'Joe Bloggs'}
```

The problem, is when I perform a GET the ObjectId I get on the client is {0000000000000...}
i.e. not the {5249.....} I'd expect. The raw response is showing the correct value, but once I deserialize I loose it.

The ObjectIdConverter code is :

```
public class ObjectIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
   }

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object  existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
     var objectId = (ObjectId)existingValue; // at this point existingValue is {000...}
     return objectId;
   }

   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
     return (objectType == typeof (ObjectId));
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implementing the `ReadJson` method of the converter incorrectly.  The `existingValue` parameter does not give you the deserialized value read from the JSON, it gives you the existing value of *the object that you will be replacing*.  In most cases this will be null or empty.  What you need to do is use the `reader` to get the value from the JSON, convert it as needed, then return the converted value.

Assuming your `ObjectId` class has a constructor that accepts a hex string, here is how you would implement the `ReadJson` method:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
    return new ObjectId(token.ToObject<string>());
}
```