# How to deserialize json object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I know that normally the method `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is used. However in this case I do a serialization, followed by a deserialization which doesn't work.

```
static public void mess(test message)
{
  try
  {
    test temp = new test(id); // The only thing I don't show is that I obtain a valid ObjectId in id
    string messageSerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp);
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test>(messageSerialized);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

I get the following exception: Error converting value "57ab57ba86597bac513ce130" to type MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'. Path 'a', line 1, position 31."

I get that the problem is the type, however how could it serialize the type but not be able to deserialize it?

Structure of test:

```
   public class test
    {
        public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId a;

        public test(MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId b)
        {
            a = b;
        }
    }


messageSerialized = "{\"a\":\"57ab57ba86597bac513ce130\"}"
```

Comment: What's the definition of `BrowsersObj`?

Comment: Json.NET can serialize a type without a public constructor, but will fail to deserialize such a type.  Possibly your data model includes such a type.  Beyond that we need a [mcve].

Comment: I could but it's a class with 15 to 20 properties, lot's of them are class containing class... is it really necessary since error is clearly on object ID property?

Comment: Then boil the class down to a single property that reproduces the problem.  That's the idea of a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like something wonky might be happening with MongoDB ObjectIds ([see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726939/mongo-db-object-id-deserializing-using-json-serializer)). Can you post your serialized JSON?

Comment: updated it with an example more complete

Comment: Are you actually running that and getting that value? I suspect it would give you json like this: `{ "a":ObjectId("57ab57ba86597bac513ce130") }`, which is not valid JSON, but is, in fact, valid BSON.

Your original question was serializing a much more complex class, which I suspect had somehow overridden something to output BSON instead of JSON. It seems possible that they overrode something in the more complex class you're trying to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: The variable messageSerialized value is as in the question I wrote. I don't have the ObjectId(). Does it mean the serialized I use do something incorrect?

Comment: OK. Perhaps you'll find a workaround in [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37966098/2041550). If so, please let me know so I can upvote it.

Comment: found something else, if it doesn't work I'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Error converting value "here is an object ID" to type
>   MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'.

Yes, look at the error and as can see it's trying to deserialize the string `"here is an object ID"` to `Bson.ObjectId` which will never succeed. You should post your serialized JSON string along with structure of `BrowsersObj`.

Per your latest edit: `"57ab57ba86597bac513ce130"` is not a MongoDB ObjectId rather it's a string. Check your MongoDB collection and most probably you are not storing the `_id` as `ObjectID` rather you have overwritten them to store as `string`

Comment: I edited it, it's an object ID actually. I didn't write it down, updated it
will add the deserialized object with structure soon