# How to write a query for orderby in mongodb for C# sort by number?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a BsonDocument like

---

```
{"_id" : "cf7efefd-91f3-4b55-8233-976a08beba69",    
"_P21id" : "#1",    
"_EntityName" : "IfcCartesianPoint",    
"_v" : "(0.,0.,0.)" }

{"_id" : "75558818-2c42-4009-8fc2-636b2435debc",
"_P21id" : "#10",
"_EntityName" : "IfcGeometricRepresentationContext",
"ContextIdentifier" : "$",
"ContextType" : "'PLAN'",
"CoordinateSpaceDimension" : "3",
"Precision" : "1.E-005",
"WorldCoordinateSystem" : "#9",
"TrueNorth" : "$"
}

{
    "_id" : "4c4a7f17-eca0-4d1d-98fe-64e8bc319f5e",
    "_P21id" : "#4",
    "_EntityName" : "IfcAxis2Placement3D",
    "Location" : "#1",
    "Axis" : "#117",
    "RefDirection" : "#119"
}
```

---

I hope the result orderby "_P21id" like

---

```
{"_id" : "cf7efefd-91f3-4b55-8233-976a08beba69",    
"_P21id" : "#1",    
"_EntityName" : "IfcCartesianPoint",    
"_v" : "(0.,0.,0.)" }

{
    "_id" : "4c4a7f17-eca0-4d1d-98fe-64e8bc319f5e",
    "_P21id" : "#4",
    "_EntityName" : "IfcAxis2Placement3D",
    "Location" : "#1",
    "Axis" : "#117",
    "RefDirection" : "#119"
}

{"_id" : "75558818-2c42-4009-8fc2-636b2435debc",
"_P21id" : "#10",
"_EntityName" : "IfcGeometricRepresentationContext",
"ContextIdentifier" : "$",
"ContextType" : "'PLAN'",
"CoordinateSpaceDimension" : "3",
"Precision" : "1.E-005",
"WorldCoordinateSystem" : "#9",
"TrueNorth" : "$"
}
```

---

How can I write the query?

Comment: you can indeed use Linq.orderby clause to order ascending or descending on the type you deserialize this document to. It should work.

Comment: Karachi Can you show me hot to write this linq ?

Comment: I made a mistake of reading BSON as JSON. You will have to convert this BSON to JSON and write a linq query against it. These questions answer what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726939/mongo-db-object-id-deserializing-using-json-serializer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097872/json-net-deserializing-mongo-objectid-is-giving-the-wrong-result

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var sort = SortBy.Ascending("_P21id");
var result = Collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(sort);
```